# POST via ajax only if validation check returns true

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation, post

I'm checking my form with RSV validator. Want to get work following: Let's say user opened page for the first time. After filling all text input boxes, when user clicks `#submit_btn` FOR THE FIRST TIME, the form submit function fires RSV (validator), validator checks if there is any error. If all right, posts data via ajax, else RSV shows error messages array with the help of `alert()`. THIS PROCEDURE ONLY FOR THE FIRST TIME

BTW: RSV - validator. If no error occured during validation process the `myoncomplete()` function returns 1.. If something went wrong it alerts. Got from [here](http://www.benjaminkeen.com/software/rsv/)

I can't get it work. Please help me to fix logic/code mistakes. Thx in advance

My JS

```
var int=null;
var counter=0;
function myOnComplete() {

    return 1;

}

$(document).ready(function () {

 $("#add_form").RSV({

        onCompleteHandler: myOnComplete,

        rules: [

            "required,name,Page name required",

            "required,title,Page title required.",


            ]

    }); 

 $("#add_form").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        dataString = $("#add_form").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "processor/dbadd.php",
            data: dataString,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result, status, xResponse) {
                //do something if ajax call is success

                int = setInterval(call, 3000);
                var message = result.msg;
                var err = result.err;
                if (message != null) {
                    $.notifyBar({
                        cls: "success",
                        html: message
                    });
                }
                if (err != null) {
                    $.notifyBar({
                        cls: "error",
                        html: err
                    });
                }
            },
            error: function (e) {
                //ajax call failed
                alert(e);
            }
        });
});
$("#submit_btn").click(function () {  

            if(counter===0){
            if(myOnComplete()===1) $('#add_form').submit();
            else return false;
            }
            else  $('#add_form').submit();
            counter++;
            }); 

            $('#autosave').click(function(){
                if($(this).is(':checked')){
                     int = setInterval(call, 3000);
                     $('#submit_btn').attr({'value':'Save&Exit'});
                }
            else{
                    $('#submit_btn').attr({'value':'Save'});
                    clearInterval(int);
                }
            });

});

function call() {
    $('#add_form').submit();
}
```

Comment: To clarify my understanding of your problem. Basically you don't want the user to submit the data via ajax two times with the same data?

Comment: No i want to validate for the first time, if all things right post via ajax, in second, ... times just post. So validation goes only first time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through the RSV code it looks like whatever you attach RSV to has its submit rebound to validate the data using .RSV.validate()

As seen here:

```
$(this).bind('submit', {currForm: this, options: options}, $(this).RSV.validate);
});
```

Which means that if you use .submit() you are calling .RSV.validate also.

So once you validate the info try binding your submit to the standard submit function.

Edit: To help explain

When you use

```
$("#add_form").RSV({...});
```

The RSV javascript code is binding .RSV.validate() to the submit event of your add_form element. Meaning when you submit your add_form form .RSV.validate() is being called before the submit.

Try running the script code below with and without the .RSV() call

This script will log ALL handlers for ALL events on the add_form element. You notice that calling $element.RSV({...}) attaches a second event handler to the submit event of the add_form element. I am unsure of the *best way* to access this event handler to .unbind() it. Good luck :)

```
jQuery.each($('#add_form').data('events'), function(i, event){
    jQuery.each(event, function(i, handler){
       console.log(handler);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, to my understanding now you only want to validate the first set of data and if that validates correctly trust the user, i got this working on jsFiddle with an easy example, i guess you can make use of that

http://jsfiddle.net/WqnYa/9/

Basically what i do is that i catch the submit button click and not the forms submit function, maybe it can be done that way, too. I assign a class "needsvalidation" and when ever the first validation passes, i simply remove that class. And if that class is not present, the validation will not be initialized due to `$(this).hasClass('needval')`

If that's not what you're looking for then your question needs way more clarity :( hope this helps though!

Comment: Thx. but that's not answer to my question. Have you read my code at all? I need solution for my situation. Do you think that I can't do such basic things like your solution?

Comment: Sorry i tried a simple solution for a complex problem. My mistake. You simply didn't explain your problem well enough. I see no difference between doing it manually or within intervals, if there's the problem with intervals explain what exactly doesn't work...

Comment: Listen: My validator is from here http://www.benjaminkeen.com/software/rsv/jquery/. What i wanna do is simple: Let's say you've entered to the page for the first time. After filling all text inputs, of course you're clicking to submit button. Now, the submit button must fire validation process. If all went right RSV returns true (i changed it to 1) via `myoncomplete()` function. I wanna post data via AJAX only if form data passed validation successfully. If not passed, RSV must alert array of error messages. Now the problem is, my code posts data without checking for validation result

Comment: Well your example is confusing, as you're hooking both, the formSubmit() and the submitClick() event. Log where your script goes to. Does it go into the myOnComplete() at all? If so is the return value as expected? Is the counter working as expected? All this are the things to check and i assume that the error is somewhere within that region :S

Comment: Can we get it work if you have a free time? i mean via teamviewer or something like that

Comment: At the moment sadly not, its late here, i will check it out tomorrow morning at work though, in case someone else didn't reply a solution by that time. That's aproximately 12 hours from now :S